# Xcode - Show segue from modal view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am presenting a modal view controller with a tableView, and then want to perform a push segue when a cell is tapped inside the modally presented view controller.

I set up a view controller and a show (push) segue from the modal view controller to the new view controller, but when I call performSegueWithIdentifier, the new view is presented in a modal fashion (slides up) on top of the initial modal view, instead of coming in from the right.

Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide relevant code or storyboard screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who has this issue in the future, I figured it out:

You need another navigation controller. So I perform a modal segue to a new navigation controller, and set the modal view controller as the root view controller of the navigation controller. I can then perform a show segue from the modal view controller to any other as normal.

:)

Comment: Hi, could you share some code to help better explain this?...thanks!

Comment: @user3708224 - here's an example of how you can accomplish this programmatically:

`myModalVC = MyModalVC();
let anotherNavigationController = UINavigationController();
anotherNavigationController.setViewControllers([myModalVC], animated: true);
present(anotherNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil);`

Answer (score 2):

As of Xcode 11.4 (possible earlier) you can also just select the destination view controller and in the right inspector pane under the attribute inspector you have the option: "Transition style" and "Presentation" which will allow you to change from Automatic to Full Screen for example. That way you can overwrite that when you use "push" from a modally presented view controller, the segue will always present the next view controller modally.